# django Many-To-One relationship model

Tags: django, database-design, relationship, one-to-many

I want to create models with this specs :

- A user has ONLY ONE profile to add extra info
- I want to users to be able to belong to ONLY ONE organization

Is it right to write this :

```
Class User(models.Model)
    name ...
    
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class organization(models.Model):
    members = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

or

```
Class User(models.Model)
    name ...
    organizatiob = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

Or I'm completely off the mark?

Comment: The second one. In the second a user refers to *exactly one* organization. An the organization can have zero, one, or more members.

Comment: Second. User should be also be a `OneToOneField` not `ForeignKey` to organization.

Comment: The first one is wrong as you couldn't bind multiple users to an organization.